# How to get all accounts from API response? Zoho API C#

Tags: c#, api, zoho

The problem which I have right now that from calling ZohO GET method, then I can get for one time call - 200 accounts, but when I'm trying to call again, then I'm getting the same 200 accounts, how can I get all my accounts?

My code:

```
        RecordOperations recordOperations = new RecordOperations();
        ParameterMap paramInstance = new ParameterMap();
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.APPROVED, "both");
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.SORT_ORDER, "asc");
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 1);
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 2);
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PER_PAGE, 200);
        paramInstance.Add(SearchRecordsParam.CRITERIA, "Account:equals:" + "Customer");
        paramInstance.Add(SearchRecordsParam.CRITERIA, "Account:equals:" + "Sub-customer");
        HeaderMap headerInstance = new HeaderMap();
        APIResponse<ResponseHandler> response = recordOperations.GetRecords(moduleAPIName, paramInstance, headerInstance);

        int totalAccounts = 0;
        if (response != null)
        {
                ResponseHandler responseHandler = response.Object;
                if (responseHandler is ResponseWrapper)
                {
                    //Get the received ResponseWrapper instance
                    ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = (ResponseWrapper)responseHandler;

                    List<Record> records = responseWrapper.Data;

                    foreach (Record record in records)
                    {
                        totalAccounts++;
                        ZohoAccount account = new ZohoAccount(record);
                        accounts.Add(account.Account_Name.ToString(), account);

                        object accountName = record.GetKeyValue("Account_Name");
                        accountNamez.Add(accountName);

                    }
                }
        }
```

I was trying to use for loop, but I got the same accounts every time. Then I was trying to put like this:
First call:

```
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 1);
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 2);
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PER_PAGE, 200);
```

Second call:

```
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 3);
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 4);
        paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PER_PAGE, 200);
```

It's also not working, so the problem is not in the pages.

Does anyone have an idea how to call other accounts?

Zoho documentation API:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/csharp-sdk/v2/record-samples.html?
There is you can find: Get all records of a module.

Comment: Why do you set parameter PAGE two times? Try for each request create its own `paramInstance' and set PAGE once.

Comment: @pakeha_by Because usually you have 100 accounts per page, so in the first call I'm getting 200 accounts, but for the next one I'm getting exactly the same 200 accounts, I'm trying to figure it out, but do not have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it's working in C#, but I found this for your case:
The page and per_page parameter is used to fetch records according to their position in the CRM. Let's assume that the user has to fetch 400 records. The maximum number of records that one can get for an API call is 200. So, for records above the 200th position, they cannot be fetched. By using the page (1 and 2) and per_page (200) parameter, the user can fetch all 400 records using 2 API calls.

Link:https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v3/get-related-records.html

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the different PAGE params to separate GetRecords calls.  Each PAGE should return a separate set of records.

The problem may be that when setting the PAGE param twice for the same GetRecords call, the 2nd PAGE setting overwrites the 1st PAGE setting.

So this code:

```
paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 1);
paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 2);
```

sets GetRecordsParam.PAGE to `1`. and then overwrites the `1` with `2` and only sends PAGE = `2` in the GetRecords request.

You can check this by printing/displaying the paramInstance data structure.